# Image display Issue into community Salesforce

Tags: salesforce-lightning

```
Facing issue with retrieving image on Salesforce Community page,

I had tried the same community image url on chrome, ie and mozilla browser.

But, this will work fine on LWC component when i am posting it on app page then image is displaying properly. ie image preview work fine on the app page but not on the community view.
```

I had also tried by giving custom URL but still the issue remains same.
When I right clicking on the small image icon displaying into community and copying the image url and posting it on browser then it was showing me the error provided as an attached screenshot of it with this post.

```
For more detail description on inspect element it was giving : error code - 503


 ---- .cls code ----
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<ContentDocument> retriveFiles(String ticketId)
  {   
   system.debug('ticketId line 10 ' + ticketId);
   List<ContentDocumentLink> listContentDocumentLink = [SELECT 
   ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =:ticketId 
   LIMIT 1];
    if (!listContentDocumentLink.isEmpty()){ 
        List<ContentDocument> listContentDocument = [SELECT Id, Title, 
   FileType, FileExtension FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id 
   =:listContentDocumentLink[0].ContentDocumentId];
        if(!listContentDocument.isEmpty()){ 
            system.debug(' listContentDocument[0] ' + 
   listContentDocument[0]);
            return listContentDocument;
        }
      }
     return null;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<FileData> GetEntityRecordFiles(string ticketId)
    {
    system.debug('BASE_URL line 10 ' + BASE_URL);
    system.debug('ticketId line 10 ' + ticketId);
    List<ContentDocumentLink> links=[SELECT ContentDocumentId,LinkedEntityId 
    FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId=:ticketId];
    Set<Id> ids=new Set<Id>();
    for(ContentDocumentLink link:links)
    {
        ids.add(link.ContentDocumentId);
    }
    List<ContentVersion> versions=[SELECT 
    VersionData,Title,ContentDocumentId,FileExtension FROM ContentVersion WHERE 
    ContentDocumentId = :ids AND IsLatest = true];
    
    List<FileData> files=new List<FileData>();
    for(ContentVersion attach:versions)
     {
        FileData data=new FileData();
        if(versions!=null && versions.size()>0)
        {
            data.Content = 
   EncodingUtil.base64Encode(versions[0].VersionData);
            data.ContentType = ContentType(versions[0].FileExtension);
           }
        data.DownloadUrl = 
   '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/'+versions[0].ContentDocumentId;
        data.FileUrl = '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload? 
   rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId='+versions[0].Id;
        this.relatedImageData.push({ Id: img.Id, url: 
   '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/' + versions[0].Id});
        files.add(data);
    }
    return files;
 }

 --CODE IN .html File------

 <template for:each={files} for:item="keyValue" >
             <tr key={keyValue.Id}>
                <template if:true={keyValue.DownloadUrl}>
                   <img src={keyValue.DownloadUrl}/>
                  </template>
              </tr>
 </template>
    
 --CODE IN .js File -----

 filePreview(event) {
    // Naviagation Service to the show preview
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__namedPage',
        attributes: {
            pageName: 'filePreview'
        },
        state : {
            // assigning ContentDocumentId to show the preview of file
            selectedRecordId: event.currentTarget.dataset.id
        }
      })
}
```

[![reported error][1]][1]

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOjSv.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic answer is: a community doesn't have the same host than salesforce app.

You're basically using an URL hack which works on salesforce app but isn't in a community because communities doesn't expose that `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/...`.

If my memories are correct, you can use `/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={fileId}` in a community.

Otherwise you can try to get the base url of the salesforce app to add before: `https://...../sfc/servlet.shepherd/...`

Please note that community login and salesforce login are not always the same so you might also have an issue with authentification.

If I understand correctly, you're trying to display thumbnails of files in your community ? We use "Lightning Image Slider" AppExchange in Salesforce app, I wonder if it works on community and for your usage.

EDIT: add community link

Comment: How can we find the complete URL of downloadURL, fileURL?

Answer (score 0):

I build one community site .I was showing file priview by your approach.It was working fine for 'Internal' users.But priview was giving error for community license users.
Below workaround worked for me

1. Write one trigger on **contentVersion** .In 'After insert ' trigger ,Create corresponding record in '**ContentDistribution**' object,
2. **PdfDownloadUrl** and **DistributionPublicUrl** fields on contentDistribution gets populated automatically.
3. Query this object and show file preview using this links.

Thanks